# How to optimize a query with multiple OR, AND, IN statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I have a an SQL query as below:

```
    Declare @ConnectionType int = 5, 
    @UserId int = 2

    select * from CallDetails 
    Where ((@ConnectionType = 0 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 1 AND CallDetails.DeviceType = 4)
            OR (@ConnectionType = 2 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,7))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 3 AND CallDetails.DeviceType = 5)
            OR (@ConnectionType = 4 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,4,7))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 5 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (4,5))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 6 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,5,7))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 7 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (8))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 8 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,7,8))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 9 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (5,8))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 10 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (4,8))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 11 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,4,8))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 12 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,5,8))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 13 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (4,5,8)) 
            OR (@ConnectionType = 14 AND CallDetails.DeviceType IN (0,1,2,3,7,4,5))
            OR @ConnectionType IS NULL)
```

Another portion of the query is:

```
            AND (@UserId IS NULL OR @ConnectionType IN (1,3,5,7,9,10,13)

            OR (@ConnectionType = 0 AND (CallDetails.DeviceType IN (4,5,8) OR (CallDetails.UserId = @UserId)))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 2 AND ((CallDetails.UserId = @UserId)))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 4 AND (CallDetails.DeviceType = 4 OR (CallDetails.UserId = @UserId)))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 6 AND (CallDetails.DeviceType = 5 OR (CallDetails.UserId = @UserId)))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 8 AND (CallDetails.DeviceType = 8 OR (CallDetails.UserId = @UserId)))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 11 AND (CallDetails.DeviceType IN (4,8) OR (CallDetails.UserId = @UserId)))
            OR (@ConnectionType = 12 AND (CallDetails.DeviceType IN (5,8) OR (CallDetails.UserId = @UserId))) 
            OR (@ConnectionType = 14 AND (CallDetails.DeviceType IN (4,5) OR (CallDetails.UserId = @UserId)))
        )
```

`@ConnectionType` is a combination of Multiple devices and at this basis `DeviceType` will be decided. Once in future any other device will be added `@ConnectionType` combinations will be increased and so on. This query is being used in multiple `Store Procedures` too. How can I optimize this query ?

Comment: This seems like you would be better off with a lookup table or using a dynamic statement (I personally would recommend the prior, as it'll likely be easier to implement).

Comment: @Larnu How to do that any clue pl ?

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned, this looks like you would be better off with a lookup table. Your table could look as simple as this (note I add no indexes, foreign key constraints, etc, but you will likely want/need them):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ConnectionLookup (ConnectionType int,
                                   DeviceType int);

INSERT INTO dbo.ConnectionLookup (ConnectionType,
                                  DeviceType)
VALUES(0,0),
      (0,1),
      (0,2),
      (0,3),
      (0,4),
      (0,5),
      (0,7),
      (0,8),
      (1,4),
      ...
      (14,0),
      (14,1),
      (14,2),
      (14,3),
      (14,4),
      (14,5),
      (14,7);
```

Then, instead, you can perform a `JOIN` on the lookup table:

```
DECLARE @ConnectionType int = 5;
        --@UserId int = 2; --Commented out, as never used.

SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM dbo.CallDetails CD
     JOIN dbo.ConnectionLookup CL On CD.DeviceType = CL.DeviceType
WHERE CL.ConnectionType = @ConnectionType;
```

This is, however, a bit of a guess, as there is a lack of sample data and expected results but should (none the less) get you on the right path

Comment: Can I put all this logic in a separate function ? Will it slow down the performance ?

Comment: Put what logic into a separate function?

Comment: This look up table which you have created @Larnu

Comment: A function isn't a table, @AfnanAhmad; they are very different object types.

Comment: This part of a query is begin used in multiple Stored procedures. How may I centralize it ?

Comment: You'll need to change each SP, @AfnanAhmad .

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to optimize:
1. add indices on the columns of your where clause, this should speed up your query
2. create a helper table (association table) with ConnectionType, DeviceType and join it
3. adjust your stored procedure and use a dynamic query, like this:

```
DECLARE @ConnectionType INT = 0,
   @UserId INT = 2,
   @DeviceTypeString NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

IF @ConnectionType = 0
   SET @DeviceTypeString = N'0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8'

IF @ConnectionType = 1
    SET @DeviceTypeString = N'4'

IF @ConnectionType = 2
   SET @DeviceTypeString = N'0,1,2,3,7'

IF @ConnectionType = 3
    SET @DeviceTypeString = N'5'

IF @ConnectionType = 4
    SET @DeviceTypeString = N'0,1,2,3,4,7'

IF @ConnectionType = 5
    SET @DeviceTypeString = N'4,5'

IF @ConnectionType = 6
    SET @DeviceTypeString = N'0,1,2,3,5,7'

IF @ConnectionType = 7
    SET @DeviceTypeString = N'8'

IF @ConnectionType = 8
    SET @DeviceTypeString = N'0,1,2,3,7,8'

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM CallDetails AS cd WHERE (@1 IS NULL OR @1 = @1) AND (cd.DeviceType IN (SELECT [Value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@2, '','')) OR cd.UserID = @3)',
    N'@1 INT, @2 NVARCHAR(100), @3 INT',
    @ConnectionType,
    @DeviceTypeString,
    @UserID
```

I do not want to be stubborn and have adapted my example to work with sp_executesql ;-)

Comment: **Never** inject parameters into a dynamic statement. Parametrise your statements using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Also, what does `WHERE 1 = 1` add to the query, other than slowing it down?

Comment: Also, you don't need all those `ELSE`s; you can simply use an `IF` for each, as it's followed by a single statement: [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce38552bc748a4298557e74d4a52d7c2). Removing the `ELSE`s and the additional tabbing will make the statement a lot of succinct.

Comment: @Larnu: WHERE 1 = 1 is only a helper to have a functional where clause, it is not really necessary, but it is easier to add the other where clause strings...
And you are right it is better to use sp_executesql, but this is an fast written example to show another option how to speed up...

Comment: for sp_executesql read: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/ 

i have written that this code shoult be in a stored procedure so sql injection is not really a problem, but as Larnu has written sp_executesql is the better option

Comment: The values you're injecting are `int`s, so they can't actually suffer injection, however, that is never an excuse to actually do it. Using injection only promotes poor/bad practices and will likely result in you/the OP to use injection on a value that isn't safe. When ever dealing with dynamic SQL, your dynamic objects should always be **properly** quoted, and your values parametrised where ever possible or otherwise, again, properly quoted in the rare cases they can't be or is difficult (for example in dynamic dynamic statements; which do exist).

Comment: @Larnu I do not want to be stubborn and have adapted my example to work with sp_executesql, I hope that is in your interest...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with two columns(ConnectionType, DeviceType) that have multiple records for each connection types. Then join call details with this table.