# Parse a single quote in parameter which is used in a dynamic SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which accepts a string username. It uses a dynamic SQL statement.

SQL by default converts 'Examp'le' to 'Exam''le' but it is still failing in cast as `nvarchar` as it should be 'Examp''''le' to work there.

Is there any way to achieve this without string manipulation to replace two quotes with 4.

Below is a sample query of what I am trying to achieve

I want the parameter to have the value `Examp'le`

```
'select * from 
tablename where name = ' + '''' + CAST(@parameter AS  nvarchar(254)) + ''''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use sp_executesql, try this:

```
DECLARE @Parameter NVARCHAR(254) = 'Value xyz...'

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM tablename AS t WHERE t.Name = @1',
N'@1 NVARCHAR(254)',
@Parameter
```

The advantages are: 1st it's more secure and 2nd you have not the problem with counting quotes ;)

For further information look at:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/

If you want more than one parameter look on my post here:
[How to optimize a query with multiple OR, AND, IN statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767497/how-to-optimize-a-query-with-multiple-or-and-in-statements/57768406#57768406)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the single quote with a double quote first. 
If you don't have a single quote in your parameter, then nothing will be replaced.

```
SET @Parameter = REPLACE(@Parameter, '''', '''''')

' SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = ''' + @parameter + ''' '
```